# CHtmlView and issue with dir=rtl

Tags: html, arabic, right-to-left

I am still working on my application (need to change behaviour of specific controls to be right-aligned etc.) but ...

I have added "dir=rtl" to the html tag of the report. Yet, in my CHtmlView it is not displaying correctly:

[image]

But, if I go to do a Print Preview, that seems to look OK to me:

[image]

What would be the cause of this behaviour?

Thanks for your help.

Andrew

Comment: I have also cut out all of the data so it is just the heading. I even changed the heading to a paragraph.

Comment: I found that if I edit my "body" class and remove the "width" and "margin" values that the data then shows in the centre of the CHtmlView.

Comment: add to report html tag: style="direction:rtl; align:right"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeating my original comment:

I found that if I edit my "body" class and remove the "width" and "margin" values that the data then shows in the centre of the CHtmlView.